# How to convert from char * to int to hex decimal in C

Tags: c

How can I convert from char * to int to hex decimal? My input is `78` and I expect `4e` but get `3465` as result.

```
int main()
{
  char *input = "78";
  int num = strtol(input, NULL, 10); // to int
  char out[2];
  sprintf(out, "%x", num); // to hex
  for(int i=0;i<2;i++)
    printf("%x\n", out[i]);
}
```

Comment: You should be using `%c` in your `printf`. Or just print your `out` as a string with `%s` in one instruction, not in a loop (but in that case, don't forget to add a NULL terminator, so need to increase array size by 1).

Comment: `printf("%s\n", out);`. And you need to make your `out` bigger. `sprintf` is overflowing it with `\0`.

Comment: Function `printf` is not really important in this case, I use it to proof weather `out` contains `4e`. Making `out` bigger does not solve my problem.

Comment: It is important, as that's where your issue is. `out` is holding the value after the 2 transformations (char * to int, int to hex), so `out` contains what you're expecting, i.e. "4e". But you're printing the hex values of those characters. You have the right answer, just displaying it wrong.

Comment: So your "proof" is wrong and not showing what it is supposed to show. Before you are using a tool to prove something, you should show your tool is working.

Comment: @haccks not sure about this duplicate because, although the *goal* is the same, this here is a *why doesn't this code work*-question ...

Comment: @FelixPalmen While I agree that it shouldn't have been closed as duplicate (because of reasons you stated), I do think it should have been closed. The code is working (almost, as you did say that `out` should be one byte longer for NULL terminator), but the issue is OP is displaying the hex values of the hex characters, and not the hex characters themselves.

Comment: @AntonH I don't see a matching close reason for that. Although this "*double hexing*" is quite peculiar, it's not unclear, not too broad, and beyond a "simple typo" ... :o (and the question contains MCVE as well)

Comment: @FelixPalmen I was thinking of the "typographical" (replace %x with %c in printf), although I do admit it is a bit of a stretch. Or "code not working ...", simply because the code *is* working.

Comment: @AntonH hmm `%c` for `%x` **would** work here when also using `snprintf()` instead of `sprintf()`. So, maybe that's enough for *typo*, but yes, it's a bit of a stretch. Because of this rather strange error, I bet you don't find a **good** duplicate as well. Leaving it closed because I *feel* it shouldn't be reopened, but really unsure about the reasoning...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is wrong:

```
char out[2];
sprintf(out, "%x", num); // to hex
```

because you write beyond the bounds of the array. Your number has two hexadecimal places, and you need an **additional** byte for the `\0` terminator of the string. It has to be at least `char out[3]`.

This is even wronger:

```
for(int i=0;i<2;i++)
  printf("%x\n", out[i]);
```

You **already** have a hexadecimal string representation of the number and now take the individual **characters** and interpret them as hexadecimal numbers. Just output your `out` string instead, e.g. `puts(out)` or `printf("%s\n", out)` (requires the `\0` terminator to be present).

You can condense the whole thing to just

```
int main(void)
{
  char *input = "78";
  long num = strtol(input, NULL, 10); // to int
  printf("%lx\n", num); // to hex
}
```

(note that `strtol()` returns `long` -- with larger numbers you'd get a problem converting this to `int`.)

Comment: and how can I store the result which is printed in a char * or char[] ?

Comment: You already do that with your `sprintf()`? The only problem there is the array was one too small, as I wrote.